Remote JMX does not work in Cassandra 4.0 and 4.1
I have created a Cassandra cluster v4.0.0 and v4.1.0. Following is the config for jvm.options file:
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7199
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=7188 (tried with port 7199 too)
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.host=<IP>
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<IP>

The problem that we are facing is this: nodetool status runs fine (without -h option)
nodetool -h <IP> status does not work. The error is this:
nodetool: Failed to connect to '<IP>:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'.
netstat -ntlp output:
admin@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx:~$ netstat -ntlp
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.54:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5012          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6062          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6162          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8126          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7199          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      -       

port 7199 is listening on localhost for Cassandra v4.x, but it listens on the  for Cassandra v3.11.13
Configurations for both versions are the same
What could be the issue here? Can someone please help?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to DBA Stack Exchange. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

It worked by adding
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7199
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=7188 (tried with port 7199 too)
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.host=<IP>
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<IP>

in the file jvm8-server.options

The node is not configured correctly which is why JMX and nodetool only works on the default localhost address.
The file jvm.options was in use all the way to Cassandra 3.11 but it was replaced in C* 4.0 by jvm-server.options when support for Java 11 was added (CASSANDRA-9608). From then on, conf/cassandra-env.sh and bin/cassandra.in.sh no longer use jvm.options.
In any case, we recommend that you configure remote JMX access in cassandra-env.sh where most admins would expect it to be configured. Cheers!
